# Delphi XE3 form Open and Close

Tags: forms, delphi

Can someone help me with this:

I have form 1 and form 2

```
in form1 1 :use form2.
in form1 put a button with code Form2.Showmodal;
form2 is made invisible
form2 has one button:
```

- form2.close = works but does not close just hides the form.
  -form2.free - either access violation or closes and the form1 is frozen (taskmngr to kill it)
- Form2. release - acccess viololation or closes..if I click the open button on form1 to reopen the form it give access violation..
- Form2.close + onClose action  :=cafree; - access violation..
- Form2.closemodal - has no effect..

how can I dispose and reuse form2 which is shown as modal from form1 ?

thanks a bunch..it has to be something simple Im overlooking.

s

Comment: Without seeing what kind of code you have in `Form2` (and `Form1` for that matter), it's difficult to understand what the issue might be.

Answer (score 3):

> form2.close = works but does not close just hides the form.

Yes, it does close the form.  That is what the default behavior of a closed form is - to hide itself.  In the case of a modal form, `Close()` merely set's the form's `ModalResult` to a non-zero value, which causes `ShowModal()` to exit and close/hide the form.

> form2.free - either access violation or closes and the form1 is frozen (taskmngr to kill it)

It is not safe to `Free()` a form from inside of an event handler belonging to the same form.  The VCL still needs to access the form object after the event handler exits.  To safely free the form, you have to use `Release()` instead, which signals the form to automatically free itself at a later time when it is safe to do so.

> Form2. release - acccess viololation or closes..if I click the open button on form1 to reopen the form it give access violation..

The only way `Release()` can cause an AV is if you are calling it using an invalid form pointer.  If re-opening a form causes an AV, then you have some serious bugs in your code.

> Form2.close + onClose action :=cafree; - access violation..

`caFree` causes the form to call `Release()` on itself.  See above.

> Form2.closemodal - has no effect..

You are not supposed to call `CloseModal()` directly.  Use `Close()` or set the `ModalResult` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove Form 2 from auto-creating.

```
Project > Options > Forms 
Remove Form 2 from "Auto-create forms"
```

This makes sure that this form is not automatically created.

When you create an instance of it, do not refer to it by its name (such as `Form2`). Instead, create a temporary variable. If you want to show it in the modal state, do it something like this:

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F: TForm2;
begin
  F:= TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    F.ShowModal;
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Don't refer to your form by any name you may have given it, such as `Form2`. If you instantiate it as another variable as demonstrated above (with `F`), then make sure all calls you make to it are through this variable. In fact, as long as you remove this form from the auto-created forms, you may completely remove the declaration to this form:

```
var
  Form2: TForm2;
```

If you want it to show in a non-modal state, while the main form is still accessible, it has to be done quite differently. Let me know if that's what you need, and I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: Ok I put the above code in the button in form1 to open form2..in form2  button i put Form2.close; that gave access violation again...

Comment: Don't call close, the code above is all you need to show the form in a modal state.

Comment: o ok I get it just using the borderIcon..but can it be done with a  Tbutton ?

Comment: Let me clarify the problem..I have a form that acts as launcher. from that form I call a second form that give the user a chance to change his password. That second form has 2 buttons..one is save the other is cancel..I need to close the form after the user clicks those buttons and I need that form completely disposed of..

Comment: So are you trying to create a form before you create the main form? Such as a splash screen or login screen?

Comment: Set the `ModalResult` of the buttons to non-zero values.  Or use the button `OnClick events to set the `ModalResult` of the modal `TForm`. Either approach will cause `ShowModal()` to exit.

Comment: OK that seem to do the trick..setting the modal result of the button closes the form and the above code disposes it cleanly..thank you guys you saved the day ..

Answer (score 0):

```
//this script for showing Form through Button with position 
//change position by changing left or top by changing 120 and 300
//in Delphi 10.3 and above 
// add form2 unit name in main unit in implementation as uses
```

//example
//implementation
//uses main;
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
F: TForm2; // Desired Form for Calling or showing
begin
F:= TForm2.Create(nil);
try
F.Left :=left+120; //Left position of Desired Form
F.Top :=top+300; //Top position of Desired Form
F.ShowModal;
finally
F.Free;
end;
end;